# smtp, phpinfo, sendmail

Tags: smtp, php

I am trying to send email using PHPmailer but when I change the SMTP server in php.ini, it is not updating in the phpinfo - it's still showing localhost. I'm assuming that this why I'm getting the error `SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host`.

Can you help me find the error and possible reasons why I can't change the SMTP server, even though I can change the smtp_port

I've already tried doing this with mail servers and I also had a lot of trouble installing pear so I just want to make this work. I've tried `smtp.mail.yahoo.com`, `smtp.gmail.com`, and our own mailserver, and it's still showing as localhost. I've also restarted each time I made the change

It's my 3rd day diagnosing the problem for sending a simple email (which I found much easier in asp.net). If you need any further information, please just let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: why did i get a vote down? unclear? what part? and i also said if you need further information just let me know because i do know it is not in the php codes because like i said the update to smtp is not reflecting in the phpinfo() so i already did this in php.ini smtp=smtp.mail.yahoo.com , smtp=smtp.gmail.com , smtp=dremail.com..no changes to smtp still showing localhost..i also googled it for 3 days straight so i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

May be a stupid question, but are you using the correct php.ini file? - in many installations there may be more than one around. I always double check that the php.ini file I am changing is the one refered to in phpinfo()

Comment: yes.i can confirm that it is the only one around because i can change the smtp port and other settings only the smtp is not changed.it really is weird when i think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking further on this, I am using phpmailer, but didn't bother setting smtp server in php.ini. Instead I create a new class that extends phpmailer, and specify my SMTP settings in there, rather like below.

This allows me to configure SMTP settings for multiple sites without ever needing to touch php.ini or the standard phpmailer files.

```
<?php
require_once('initialise.inc.php');  // Initialising constants including LIB_PATH & DS
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."phpmailer".DS."class.phpmailer.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."phpmailer".DS."class.smtp.php");

class my_phpmailer extends phpmailer {

    public $From = "me@example.com"; // Email Address
    public $FromName = "My Name"; // Name
    public $Host = "mailserver.example.com";
    public $Mailer = "smtp";
    public $WordWrap = 75;
    public $Username = "***************"; // SMTP account username
    public $Password = "********"; // SMTP account password


    function __construct() {
    }

    public function __toString() {
    return $this;
    }
```